# is array a<T, N> = { initializer-list }; correct syntax?

Tags: c++, c++11

In the working draft http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3225.pdf 23.3.2 it says

> An array is an aggregate (8.5.1) that can be initialized with the
>   syntax `array a<T, N> = { initializer-list };`

I would have throught `array<T, N> a = { initializer-list };` would be correct, can someone explain this odd syntax?

Comment: [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The draft is in error. The final version of the C++11 standard has `array<T, N> a` as you would expect.

Comment: thank you, I thought I was insane there for a minute.